# Compute distance between vector and matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy

I am using `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.paired_distances` to calculate distances between a single vector and a matrix. I want to calculate the distance between every row of the matrix and the single vector. Since `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.paired_distances` requires the two arrays to have equal dimensions, I use `np.tile` to create a matrix which contains multiple copies of the vector to create a matrix that has the same size as the first one.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import paired_distances

# get matrix a and vector b
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
b = np.array([[5],[6]]).transpose()

# create a matrix with copies of b that has the same size as matrix a
b = np.tile(b,(a.shape[0],1))

distances = paired_distances(a,b)
```

Just out of curiosity: Is there a function that does that out of the box? Time is not critical here, since I don't deal with very big arrays. But the function should offer different kinds of metrics.

Comment: You can use  SciPy's `cdist` : `cdist(a,b).ravel()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `numpy.apply_along_axis` method to apply a given function to each rows.