# Calculation of Mahalanobis distance doesn't work when using scipy's cdist function

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy, distance

I want to calculate the mahalanobis distance between every row of a matrix and a single row vector. Originally, I used `np.tile` to create a matrix that contains multiple copies of the vector to create an equal shaped matrix and then used `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.paired_distances` to calculate the distances row-wise.

I wanted to know if there's a more readable alternative to this, that is why I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58917135/compute-distance-between-vector-and-matrix) a few weeks ago. User **Divakar** came up with the idea to use `cdist(a,b).ravel()`. I found this alternative more readable and therefore used it. I tested out both functions with `metric='euclidean'` and found that they produce the same result. However, when I switch the metric to `metric='mahalanobis'` (which I want to use now), the first method seems to work but the `cdist` alternative throws the following error:

> ValueError: The number of observations (3) is too small; the
>   covariance matrix is singular. For observations with 3 dimensions, at
>   least 4 observations are required.

Can someone explain what is going on here? Why do the functions give the same results when using euclidean distance but not when using Mahalanobis distance?

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import paired_distances
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

# get matrix a and vector b
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
b = np.array([[7],[8],[9]]).transpose()

# define metric
METRIC = 'mahalanobis'

# define distance function that computes the distance between each row of a matrix
# and another matrix that contains duplicates of the single input vector.
def vector_to_matrix_distance(matrix_array,vector_array,metric):
    vector_array_tiled = np.tile(vector_array,(matrix_array.shape[0],1))
    return paired_distances(matrix_array,vector_array_tiled)

# run distance function
distances_1 = vector_to_matrix_distance(matrix_array=a,
                                     vector_array=b,
                                     metric=METRIC)

# Use cdist to do the SAME calculation.This works when METRIC = 'euclidean' but
# not when METRIC = 'mahalanobis'
distances_2 = cdist(a,b,metric=METRIC).ravel()
```

Comment: I think `distances_1` only seems to work, since you do not pass the `metric` argument anywhere in the call of `paired_distances`. On my system with sklearn version 0.21.3 `paired_distances` does not accept `mahalanobis` as a metric.

Comment: Oh God...You're right..now I feel very stupid.